# Google Cloud signed Url +SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

Trying to get a signed url for downloading a file in Google storage is problematic. Getting SignatureDoesNotMatch Error.

```
private  String signString(GoogleCredential credential, String stringToSign) throws Exception {

// sign data
Signature signer = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
signer.initSign(credential.getServiceAccountPrivateKey());
signer.update(stringToSign.getBytes("UTF-8"));
byte[] rawSignature = signer.sign();

return new String(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(rawSignature, false), "UTF-8");
```

}

```
//Here is the code to get signed url
private getFileUrl(GoogleCredential credential,String bucketName, String filePath) {
    String signedParam = signString(credential, "GET\n\n\n"+expiration+"\n"+bucketName+"/"+filePath);

   // construct URL
   String url = "http://storage.googleapis.com/" + bucketName + "/" + filePath +
                "?GoogleAccessId=" + credential.getServiceAccountId() +
                "&Expires=" + expiration +
                "&Signature=" + URLEncoder.encode(signedParam, "UTF-8");
   return url;
}
```

Am I missing anything here? Struggling with this for a while. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The bucket name in the GET path of the signed url should be preceeded by "/". This resolved the issue.

```
String signedParam = signString(credential, "GET\n\n\n"+expiration+"\n/"+bucketName+"/"+filePath);
```